# Text is not being centered

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I want to center all the text in BodyAbout.js. Text-align isn't working nor is padding-left of left. I'm not repeating the class name and thats I can think is reason its not working.

```
function BodyAbout() {
    return (
        <div className='Body__About'>
        <div className='Body__Header'>
        <h2>About</h2>
        </div>
        

        <div className='Body__Paragraph'>
        <p>Founded in 2010, we are a creative agency that</p>
        <p>produces lasting results for our clients. We’ve</p>
        <p>partnered with many startups, corporations, and</p>
        <p>nonprofits alike to craft designs that make real</p>
        <p>impact. We’re always looking forward to creating</p>
        <p>brands, products, and digital experiences that</p>
        <p>connect with our clients' audiences.</p>
      
        </div>

     
            </div>
```

BodyAbout CSS

```
  .Body__About {
    background-color: #e7816b;
    height: 30em;
    text-align: center;
    
  }
```

BodyAbout is the component

```
function About() {
    return (
        <div>
      <Navbar />
      <AboutUsImage />
      <BodyAbout/>
     <WorldClassImg />
      <MidPageDescAboutDesign Title='World-class talent'/>
   <LandmarkImages  Circle='/images/bg-pattern-small-circle.svg'/>
      <RealDeal />
      <MidPageDescAboutDesign Title='The real deal'/>
      <AboveFooter />
      <Footer /> 
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: BodyAbout.js needs closing brackets for the function and return: `)}`

Answer (score 0):

p is commonly a block-level element and may have `text-align: left` assigned to it from another CSS. Try:

```
  .Body__About {
    background-color: #e7816b;
    height: 30em;
  }
  .Body__Paragraph p {
    text-align: center;
  }
```

Comment: @Coll your 2nd comment about changing `className` to `class` is not correct the question is about react where you need to use `className` to assign classes

Comment: @ShmiliBreuer Missed ReactJS in the tags! Removed

Answer (score 0):

text-align will only center the element's inline contents, **it does not center the element itself**.

If it is a block element (a div), you need to set margin: 0 auto;

**What it does**

The margin: 0 auto; will set top and bottom margin to 0 and left and right margin to auto, this will automatically put the elements content in the center. This only works if the block element in question has a known width (fixed or relative), otherwise it may not work.

If it is an inline-element, set text-align: center; on its parent element instead.

**Alternatively** you could just target the elements children in css, something like this may work:

```
 .Body__About .Body__Paragraph p{
    text-align: center;
  }
```

You may not need the p tag but I included it just in case, that will center align all the p elements inside Body_Paragraph

Answer (score 0):

Try adding these three style properties to the container

```
.Body__About{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try these**

.Body__About {

```
 display: flex;

 justify-content:center;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

For vertical and horizontal alignment, please use the below code

```
.Body__About {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
  }
```